# How to send User ID and Password after registration to email ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an .aspx registration page. I have written code using C#. In the registration page user can register himself entering his email id and an password. I want to send the email id and password to user email id which a user input during the time of registration after successfully submitting the page. How can is send the user id and password. please suggest me some code.

I have written this simple code for registration

```
 string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
                            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//uploadimage//" + str);
                            string path = "~//upload//" + str.ToString();
                            con.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Registration(memberid,loginemailid,password,firstname,lastname,dob,maritalstatus,photo,about,lastattended,years,slno,indexno,qualification,years1,specialachivements,currentoccupation,companyname,currentdesignation,preadd,precity,prestate,prepin,peradd,percity,perstate,perpin,mobileno,officeno,telno,emailid) values('" + mid + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + dob + "','" + DropDownList4.Text + "','" + path + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + DropDownList5.Text + "','" + DropDownList6.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + drop1 + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','" + TextBox12.Text + "','" + TextBox13.Text + "','" + TextBox14.Text + "','" + TextBox15.Text + "','" + TextBox16.Text + "','" + TextBox17.Text + "','" + TextBox18.Text + "','" + TextBox19.Text + "','" + TextBox20.Text + "','" + TextBox21.Text + "','" + TextBox22.Text + "','" + mobno + "','" + TextBox25.Text + "','" + TextBox26.Text + "','" + TextBox27.Text + "')", con);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            Response.Redirect("Successfull.aspx");
```

Comment: **Never** send a password in an email.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: 1) Your code is wide open to **SQL injection attacks**.  Please use parameterized queries or some kind of ORM.  2) ***Never store user passwords in plain text.*** 3) ***Never display a user's password on the screen or send it in an email.***  What you're doing is *grossly irresponsible* to your users.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven, authentication system.

Comment: i want to send a confirmation mail. how can i do that

Comment: @AbhishekPradhan: A quick Google search for "send email in .NET" will get you started.  But please, ***please*** do not send user passwords over email.  It's one of the absolute worst things you can do to your users.

Comment: Your question is too generic for StackOverflow. Just google "how to send activation email using asp.net c#", there's plenty of material available.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "Too Broad". You haven't made an attempt to send the email, and you haven't described how you'd want to send the email (SMTP, SendGrid, file pickup, Exchange Web Services etc).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, it really is not a good idea to send/store passwords in plain text, that being said, here is an example you can modify to send a confirmation email:

```
try
{

    MailMessage notification;
    SmtpClient Client;

    notification = new MailMessage();
    notification.From = new MailAddress(YourEmail.Text, Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(TextName.Text));
    notification.To.Add(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Contact Email"].ToString()));

    notification.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    notification.Subject = "Confirmation email " + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(YourSubject.Text);
    notification.IsBodyHtml = false;
    notification.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    notification.Body = "account: " + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(TextName.Text) + "\n\npassword: " + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(passwordtext.Text);

    Client = new SmtpClient();
    try
    {
        Client.Send(notification);
    }
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
        // write a log entry here, maybe notify user of error
        return false;
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.dynamicJavaScript.Text = "<script>alert(\"Error sending message: " + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message.Replace("'","`")) + "\")</script>";

    return false;
}
this.dynamicJavaScript.Text = "<script>alert(\"Message Sent.\")</script>";
return true;
```

in your web.config file you need to configure you mail settings under  `<system.net>` as an example:

```
<mailSettings using outlook>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yourEmailAddress">
    <network host="yoursmtphost" userName="EmailLoginUserName" password="password here" port="??" >
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

I would recommend that if a user does not know, or forgets their password, set up a reset password page.

Comment: By _not a good idea to send/store passwords in plain text_ I assume you mean `terrible idea that should die in a gasoline fire`.